# Conversão de Moeda Utilizando API jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

Estou fazendo uma conversão de Moeda Chinesa (Yuan) para a Moeda Brasileira (Real). Estou utilizando a API do site: `https://free.currencyconverterapi.com`. Acontece que não consigo definir o valor a ser convertido, a conversão só retorna o resultado de uma conversão de valor `1`. Como se estivesse convertendo ¥ 1 para a moeda `Real`. Porém no meu código eu quero converter ¥ 200 para a moeda `Real`. Código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#resultado').html('Convertendo...');
 
 var moeda = { CNY_BRL: 200 };
 
 $.ajax({
   url: 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=CNY_BRL&compact=ultra&apiKey=873041c527593ec7e31e',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
  moeda = data.CNY_BRL;
  console.log(moeda);
   $( "#resultado" ).html(moeda);
   }
 })
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
O valor convertido é: <span id="resultado"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo abaixo, analisando a api percebi que ela faz exatamente o que você informou, mas você deve multiplicar o valor a ser convertido pelo resultado, como fiz abaixo!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#resultado').html('Convertendo...');
     
 $.ajax({
   url: 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=CNY_BRL&compact=ultra&apiKey=873041c527593ec7e31e',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
  moeda = data.CNY_BRL;
  console.log(moeda*200);
   $( "#resultado" ).html(moeda*200);
   }
 })
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```